# Catch running css transition with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to catch a running css transition to have some sort of an event-function as `jQuery('#element').resize();` so I can smoothley adjust my layout which is partly generated by jQuery.

I already found plenty of articles where transitionend is described. Sadly the event is only triggered when - you might guess it - the transition ended. But I'm looking for an event, that keeps triggering **until** the transition ended.

Comment: Plenty of useful topics here: https://www.google.se/search?q=jquery+css+transition+event&oq=jquery+css+transition+event&aqs=chrome.0.57j60j62l2.4587j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mention, that I'm not looking for transitionend.

Comment: Okay thanks... maybe I'll find a workaround

Comment: Set time interval to read css properties once animation starts using `.css()`, clear interval once transition ends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, and as specified by the W3, the only JavaScript event that fires as a result of a CSS transition is the `transitionend` event. There are no other events described in the spec, let alone implemented.

References:

- [CSS transition events](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/).